# Break in a for loop

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, break

I ask the user to enter name of 3 cities.  I create a list and then passing them to this function to make sure the city names are not duplicate:

```
def UniqueName(citylist):
    output = []
    for x in citylist:
       if x not in output:
           output.append(x)
       else: print "The city name you enter is part of the list"
             break
    return output
```

The problem is that it doesn't break.

Comment: It would help if you actually included the programming language you are using in the list of tags.

Comment: If it doesn't break that means all city names are unique.

Comment: If I enter Dallas Dallas the program should break and it doesn't

Comment: @pedro What programming language is this?

Comment: Please show some sample input and sample output, so as to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your indentation is wrong. It should be:

```
def UniqueName(citylist):
    output = []
    for x in citylist:
        if x not in output:
            output.append(x)
        else:
            print "The city name you enter is part of the list"
            break
    return output
```

Once you fix that, then it seems to work just fine.

Test program:

```
print UniqueName(["Dallas","Dallas","Provo"])
```

Output:

```
The city name you enter is part of the list
['Dallas']
```

Answer (score 0):

To "uniquify" a list, you can convert it to a set (and back to a list, if you need it in list form):

```
cities = ['new york', 'london', 'paris', 'london']
cityset = set(cities)
citylist = list(cityset)
```

citylist will contain (not necessarily in the same order):

```
['new york', 'london', 'paris']
```

I believe this is fairly efficient as well.

Comment: The question is about why his loop does not break, not how to check if all elements of a list are unique.

Comment: Yes, but if avoiding the loop provides a better solution to the stated problem, is it not a good answer?  E.g. "It takes me too long to get from New York to Boston, how can I prevent my horse from getting tired?"  "Get a car."